Generalization of Bertrand-Diguet-Puiseux Theorem
Let $M$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $p \in M$. The Bertrand–Diguet–Puiseux theorem states that the Gaussian curvature is given by:
$$K(p) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} 3 \frac{2\pi r - C^M_p(r)}{\pi r^3}$$
where $C^M_p(r)$ denotes the circumference of the geodesic circle of radius $r$ centered at $p$ in $M$.
Is there a generalization for higher dimensions?
Unfortunately the Gaussian curvature is only intrinsic for even dimensions. But at least the absolute value is always intrinsic (see this answer). By doing a rough calculation for hyperspheres I came to the following conjecture for $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds ($n \geq 2$):
$$|K(p)| = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \left(\frac{3\ \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{(n-1) \pi^\frac{n}{2}}\cdot\frac{\left| S^{\mathbb{R}^n}_p(r)- S^M_p(r) \right|}{r^{n+1}}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
where $S^M_p(r)$ denotes the surface area of the geodesic sphere of radius $r$ centered at $p$ in $M$.
Can this or something similar be true?
